# Or statement isn't functioning properly

Tags: php

I want to be redirected if I don't have an account1 or if I don't have an account2. The problem is, even if I have account1 it is redirecting me:

```
if(($_SESSION['account'] != "account1") || ($_SESSION['account'] != "account2")){
    header("location:/home");
    exit();
}
```

It works properly and doesn't redirect me when I have account1 when I don't include the OR:

```
if($_SESSION['account'] != "account1"){
    header("location:/home");
    exit();
}
```

but I also need it to not redirect if they, by chance, have account2.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic is wrong; you probably meant AND instead of OR. `$_SESSION['account']` can only have one value at any given time, so it's always going to be different than `account1` OR different than `account2`.

So the code should read

```
if(($_SESSION['account'] != "account1") && ($_SESSION['account'] != "account2")){
    header("location:/home");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
if(($_SESSION['account'] != "account1") && ($_SESSION['account'] != "account2")){
    header("location:/home");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is wrong :) Assuming that you have an account2, the first comparison is true, and you get redirected. You need to combine the conditions with AND (&&).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to check ($_SESSION['account'] != "account2"). You seem to have them reversed in the second condition.